# Why titling the movie with "The Killing of a Sacred Deer (2017) "

Tags: title, the-killing-of-a-sacred-deer

I just saw [the movie trailer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4oRkIhpgoRA) by a push of YouTube advertisement, the movie title drew my attention because I am happening working on conceptual analysis of one my project item material which with a unclear imagery of deer skull which derived from DeviantArt [Twitter post](https://twitter.com/DeviantArt/status/935336211006328832).  I checked and read [the Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Killing_of_a_Sacred_Deer) of the movie and other Google searched pages, I don't see anything close, so, please help me for the answer of the titled question.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Movie is titled "The Killing of a Sacred Deer" because it is conceptually based on a Greek play "Iphigenia in Aulis", according to the movie's Wikipedia page. The titular Deer is a reference to the end of the play, where the character Iphigenia, is transformed into a deer after she was killed and set on an altar. Heres the wikipedia link for the play: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iphigenia_in_Aulis